# Are these two connectors compatible?

Tags: connector, ribbon-cable

I want to use this ribbon connector ([T812110A101CEU](http://ro.farnell.com/amphenol/t812110a101ceu/socket-idc-s-relief-2-54mm-10way/dp/2215247?ost=T812110A101CEU)) with its corresponding PCB connector.

It is unclear if I should use the one with the **short latch** ([T816110A1R101CEU](http://ro.farnell.com/amphenol/t816110a1r101ceu/header-s-latch-ra-2-54mm-10way/dp/2215276?ost=T816110A1R101CEU&searchView=table&iscrfnonsku=false&ddkey=http%3Aro-RO%2FElement14_Romania%2Fsearch)) or the **long latch** ([T816110A1S102CEU](http://ro.farnell.com/amphenol/t816110a1s102ceu/header-l-latch-str-2-54mm-10way/dp/2217528)). Which is compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connector you have chosen includes the strain relief bridge. As such you need the long latch. If you decide not to use the strain relief bridge, you will need the short latch version.